# Rolling two dices until dice1 is larger than dice2 two times in java

Tags: java, loops, dice

The output of the dices are randomized and I created a function for that.
I want to record how many "attempts" it took to get dice one to be larger than dice 2 two times in a row. So when it is larger two times in a row, I would like it to print ("it took" + trials + "for d1 to be larger than d2 two times in a row"). So far I have this but am stuck:

```
public static int Dice() {
  return (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

              int d1 = Dice();
              int d2 = Dice();
              int trials = 0;

              for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
               if (t1 > t2) {
               trials++;
               if (t1 > t2) {
                trials++ 
               }
              }
             }

            System.out.println(trials);
    } 
}
```

Comment: why are you using a 100,000 count loop for this? a simple while loop control count until you get 2 d1's greater than d2's would be preferable and the loop would end when your condition is met and not keep going.

Comment: All of these answers are using the (very old, not reliably random) `Math.random()` method to generate random numbers. The better thing to use these days is the `java.util.Random` class. Create a class field `private static Random RANDOM = new Random()` and then call `RANDOM.nextInt(6) + 1` when you need a random `int` from 1 to 6.

Comment: Could you give a description of what you call a trial in your case? Are both dice thrown simultaneously two times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SO! This should work. See the comments for a few things you were doing wrong and some explanation.

```
public static int Dice() {
  return (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

  // initialize variables to be updated in the loop
  int trials = 0;
  Boolean lastTimeD1WasGreater = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
    // always increment the counter!
    trials++;

    // you had the wrong variable names here.
    // also they must be INSIDE the loop or else they would always come out the same
    int d1 = Dice();
    int d2 = Dice();

    if (d1 > d2) {
      if (lastTimeD1WasGreater) {
        // if it was greater both last time and this time then we're done!
        System.out.println("it took " + trials + " trials.");
        break;
      } else {
        // otherwise set this variable so we can be on the lookout next time.
        lastTimeD1WasGreater = true;
      }
    } else {
      // d1 was not greater, so we'll start looking for a pair in the next loop.
      lastTimeD1WasGreater = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!! This really helped me understand

Comment: Great! Let me know if you have any more questions. If I've solved your problem please click the check mark to accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (treat the following as pseudo code):

```
public static int[] Dice() {
    int[] diceThrownTwoTimes = new int[2];
    diceThrownTwoTimes[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
    diceThrownTwoTimes[1] = (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
    return diceThrownTwoTimes;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int trials = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        int[] d1 = Dice();
        int[] d2 = Dice();
        if (d1[0] > d2[0] && d1[1] > d2[1]) {
            trials++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(trials);
}
```

EDIT:

To get attempts before which dice1 value is bigger than dice2 value two times in a row, the following can be done:

```
public static int[] Dice() {
    int[] diceThrownTwoTimes = new int[2];
    diceThrownTwoTimes[0] = (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
    diceThrownTwoTimes[1] = (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
    return diceThrownTwoTimes;
} 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int trials = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        int[] d1 = Dice();
        int[] d2 = Dice();
        if (d1[0] > d2[0] && d1[1] > d2[1]) {
            break;
        }else{
            trials++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(trials);
}
```

Comment: I'd say that it would read more clearly if you used `d1[0] > d1[1] && d2[0] > d2[1]` but functionally the two expressions test exactly the same thing (in this context).

Comment: @Bobulous, yes that's true ... but since the question is to record how many attempts it took to get dice one to be larger than dice 2 two times in a row, I coded it this way :)

Comment: I'm reading `d1` to mean "roll one" and `[0]` to mean "first dice in the pair", but to be fair it could be read either way.

Comment: By the way, this code runs exactly as you've typed it (in Java 8) and gives the answer I was expecting it to, given that the correct probability is ((1+2+3+4+5)/36)^2 = 0.173611111111 (and the first run of this code gave me 17324 / 100000 = 0.17324).

Comment: I have to point out that while this code does correctly answer the question "what proportion of two-pair rolls will see the first dice larger than the second dice in both pairs", the OP actually seems to want to know just how many two-pair rolls are required before this outcome occurs just once. So this answer is useful but does not answer the OP's stated question.

Comment: @Bobulous, thanks for pointing that out ... modified my answer

Comment: Your second block of code doesn't work because it's returning a value of zero in many cases. (You need to increment the value of `trials` before the trial is evaluated, otherwise you exit without counting that trial.)

Comment: That's not the same as what the question is asking since the second roll in one invocation of Dice() and the first of the next could satisfy the requirement. Each roll has to be made independently.

Comment: @Bobulous, we need the number of attempts before the actual event of interest occurs - if it occurs in the first trial, then the answer should be zero, right?

Comment: @nvioli, could you please elaborate? Each roll in my case is independent

Comment: You're throwing both dice twice, then if those two throws don't have the desired property, you throw them both two more times. You've made four throws of a pair of dice. If the second throw from the first pair of throws and the first throw from the second pair each had the right property, you would miss it. Look at this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/238313/why-does-phh-differ-from-pth

Comment: There's a probabalistic difference between successive individual throws (what the question is asking about) and successive pairs of throws (what your answer models).

Comment: @nvioli, ok, I think I get what you are saying ... I was thinking the scenario is that both dice are thrown simultaneously, but that may not be the case

Comment: In honesty, I don't think the OP makes the specification clear enough, so I've voted to close as "Unclear..."

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with

```
public static int Dice() {
  return (int)(Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  int trials = 0;
  int count = 0;

  while (count < 2) {
    int d1 = Dice();
    int d2 = Dice();

    if (d1 > d2) {
      ++count;
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }

    ++trials;
  }

  println("It took " + trials + " trials for d1 to be larger than d2 " + count + " times in a row.")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this in the main function unless it is a requirement to use an outside function to return the random.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
      int d1 = 0;
      int d2 = 0;
      int trials = 0;
      int d1bigger = 0;
      Random rand = new Random();

      while(d1bigger < 2)
      {
            d1 = rand.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) + 1 ;
            d2 = rand.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) + 1 ;
            if(d1 > d2)
            {
                d1bigger ++;
                trials++;
            }
            if(d2 > d1)
            {
                d1bigger = 0;
                trials++;
            }                
      }
      System.out.println("It took " + trials +  " trials for d1 to be larger than d2 two times in a row");
}
```

It took 7 trials for d1 to be larger than d2 two times in a row

Sample output

Comment: if you run this with system outs for the d1 and d2 you will see the rand function operates correctly for the numbers 1 - 6

Comment: Okay, someone has used `java.util.Random.nextInt(int)` but why have you gone with the bewildering `(6-1)+1` argument when just `6` would give you the same thing more clearly?

Comment: if you look at some of the documentation for it it makes the random call more easily understood and why you need to add 1 twice not once. (( 6 - 1) + 1) + 1 ((max - min) + min) + min.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with

```
import java.util.Random;
```

public class main {

```
public static int Dice() {
    return (int) (Math.random() * 6.0) + 1;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rand = new Random();


    int trials = 0;
    int twoTimes = 0;

    do {
        int d1 = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
        int d2 = rand.nextInt(25) + 1;
        trials++;
        if (d1 > d2) {
            twoTimes++;
            System.out.printf("%s time greater\nd1 was " + d1 + "\nd2 was " + d2 + "\n-------\n", twoTimes);
        }
    }

    while (twoTimes != 2);
    System.out.printf("\nIt took %s times", trials);

}
```

}